# StringBuilder.Append not working

Tags: c#, json, string

We have a WCF project where JSON responses are generated automatically but in one scenario we are creating the JSON manually and sending it to browser. That part works fine.

Last night I noticed a bug and tried to figure it out but the problem is really strange. Somehow after concatenating the string values, a block gets removed and I don't have an idea what happened here. See the following code, what is happening?

[image: My code that is causing the problem]

Following is the snapshot of JSON after the "innerBlock" return data

[image: Result returned after innerBlock]

Following is the snapshot of JSON after string append!

[image: Result returned after concatenation]

Comment: So just to make sure I am understanding correctly, is the first snapshot one of the "innerBlock" variable, and the second is one of "jsonComplete"?

Comment: get you post the code for getLoactions().  Please post the code not an image of the code.

Comment: How is the `innerBlock` variable defined? Is it possible that it's accessed by other threads?

Comment: @LeviBotelho Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @RichardSchneider the code of getLocations() is too much and the data returned by the function correct. Exactly what i want. But somehow 2 lines afters fetching the data, the data gets faulted.

Comment: @w0lf seems to on right track.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of innerBlock and jsonComplete? What are they? I guess jsonComplete is a StringBuilder?

Comment: Guys, thank you problem solved. The JSON viewers are buggy. Both of the following are not showing the proper value. I checked the JSON in notepad and it was fine. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/,http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net application was working fine. Since, my JSON was too big, I was using some JSON viewers, but unfortunately they had bugs. Tested the JSON in notepad and things were working fine.

1. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu
2. http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Did you report the bugs to the JSON viewer authors?